# Python: execute shell command using variable

Tags: python, ipv6, ifconfig

In my Lab I need to change the interface on a server to a random IPv6 address. I have two scripts. The first script makes up a random IPv6 address and works perfectly. I'm trying to take the output of that script and use it as a variable in the second script. Then run an ifconfig command to set that IPv6 address on that interface. That's the general run down of what I'm trying to do.
Below is the script that generates the random IPv6 address, ipv6_gen.py

```
from random2 import seed, getrandbits
from ipaddress import IPv6Network, IPv6Address

subnet = u'1234:5678:ab:cde::/64'

seed()
network = IPv6Network(subnet)
address = IPv6Address(network.network_address + getrandbits(network.max_prefixlen - network.prefixlen))

print(address)
```

This one should take the output of the first and execute the ifconfig command.

```
import ipv6_gen
import os, commands
import subprocess
import shlex

ipv6=ipv6_gen
shell_cmd = ("sudo ifconfig en0 inet6 add %s" %ipv6)

subprocess_cmd = shlex.split(shell_cmd)
subprocess.call(subprocess_cmd)
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
ubuntu:~$ python change_ipv6.py 
1234:5678:ab:cde:8087:1bb6:b264:acdd
<module: Host name lookup failure
getaddrinfo: ipv6_gen: -3
ipv6_gen: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
```

when I run ifconfig the IPv6 address isn't set. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, tried researching this for awhile now and got nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember that `ifconfig` is obsolete on Linux systems and you should use `ip` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second script looks a bit odd.

You assign module `ipv6_gen` to a variable `ipv6` and then use it for shell command.

Try this version:

```
import ipv6_gen
import os, commands
import subprocess
import shlex

ipv6 = ipv6_gen.address
shell_cmd = ("sudo ifconfig en0 inet6 add %s" % ipv6)

subprocess_cmd = shlex.split(shell_cmd)
subprocess.call(subprocess_cmd)
```

Comment: Your change worked!! Thank you.
I guess now I'm trying to understand why the (.address) made it work?

Comment: This really is something you ought to know when using Python. Any tutorial about `modules`, `packages` and importing in Python will do. [This](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1) one should help you.

Comment: If I may, I would probably still recommend a bit more work and define function returning address in `ipv6_gen` rather then do all in its `__main__` and access its variable.

Comment: I should've started saying I'm a noob with scripting and python. I can piecemeal bits from other scripts to make it work for me. But I'm trying to understand more. Thanks for the link.